# destroy controller routing to show view (rails 4.1.8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, show, destroy

Been struggling through the rails guide build a blog tutorial. Have, I think, everything working aside from the destroy link on the index page. When clicked, it routes to the show view for that article that's clicked on to be deleted. this is from the index.html.erb. any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    def destroy 
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
end 

private
    def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
```

Comment: what do you have in index views?

Comment: use this to build your link: `<%= link_to 'Destroy', articles_path(@article), method: :delete %>` most probably you are missing the method param

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', articles_path(@article), method: :delete %>
```

The reason why the `method` option is required is because a browser cannot send a `DELETE` command necessary to perform the action. Providing the option sets an extra attribute and lets rails know the action you are about to perform should be routed to the `deletion` route instead of a simple `show`

Have a look at:
 [Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)